# OpenLayers 4 getGetFeatureInfoUrl and HitTollerance

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using this piece of code

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {

...
url = pmfeatlayer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(coordinate, viewResolution, projection, {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});

if (url) {...
}
...
}
```

And here my layer:

```
pmfeatlayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  extent: ext,
  preload: Infinity,
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: Settings.url,
    params: {'LAYERS': sQLayers, MYORDERS: Settings.order, DTO: DTo, format: 'image/png'},
    ratio: 1.1,
    gutter: 40
  })
});
```

to get the feature info on `pmfeatlayer`, Inside all the code I have also a function that displays a list of the feature in that pixel (If I have more than 1 URL create a list of them)

How can I increase the tolerance?

I found this example but I can't get it work, is this just for features or also for layers?

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/hit-tolerance.html

Here a screenshot of my map.

[image]

I have a `map layer` and a `featlayers` (all the street restriction are on that layer) and as you can see from the popup at that pixel I have 2 restrictions, how can I increase the radius o get also the 2 street sign for example (because at the moment he display the 2 street line but not the signs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I make it works with `FEATURE_COUNT:10`,`buffer` doesn't work.

Checking the Request WMS URL I found `FEATURE_COUNT:10`, in another version of the project with others type of data, a parameter that is not present in the old code, I'm still unable to understand how OL2 has inserted this parameter in the URL

Answer (score 0):

The example you're looking at is slightly different because it is using a vector layer, where all the geometries are already added to the map. Because you're making a getFeatureInfoRequest you can't apply a hit tolerance in OpenLayers. Instead you can try adding a buffer param in the getFeatureInfoUrl function, as `{'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'BUFFER': 5}`. This requests that the map server include any geometries within this buffer area in its response. If that doesn't work you could try adding a maxFeatures param, indicating the maximum amount of feature's you'd want to get back from the map server, as it may be that the server is defaulting to only giving one feature back.

Comment: Monday I'll try, I'm not exactly sure how it works because in the request of OpenLayer 2 I found the parameter `FEATURE_COUNT:10` but is not present on the code, so I assume that OL2 do that for you, in OL4 there is no such parameter but still you have more than 1 result. Is `buffer` a MapServer parameter?